# ORA-00604, ORA-01000 errors in C# with Oracle; max open cursors exceeded

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

Hi all:  I have a program that is running 4 threads that talk to an Oracle database.  I have the Oracle connections local to each thread, and I'm employing the USING statement as well as manually closing the recordset and closing the connection.  As I understand it, the ORA-01000 error arises when there are more open recordsets than configured cursors on the database.  I do not understand why my recordsets are staying open or why I'm getting this error.  Here's the code:

```
    static void CheckPaths()
    {
        int pathcount = paths.Count; //paths is a typed list           
        Parallel.ForEach(paths, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (p) =>
        {
            try
            {
                CheckSinglePathAllHours(p);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //there is logging here, this is where the exception hits
            }
        });
    }

    static void CheckSinglePathAllHours(Path p)
    {
        string sqlBase = @"Select * from table ";//this is actually a big SQL statement
        using (DBManager localdbm = new DBManager())
        {
                string sql = sqlBase;             
                OracleDataReader reader = localdbm.GetData(sql);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                       //process the path, query always returns 24 or less rows
                }
                reader.Close();
                reader = null; //is this even necessary?               
                localdbm.Close(); //is this necessary in conjunction with the USING statement?
        }
    }

class DBManager : IDisposable
{
    OracleConnection conn;
    OracleCommand cmd;
    public DBManager()
    {
        string connStr = "blah blah blah";            
        conn = new OracleConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    }
    public OracleDataReader GetData(string sql)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    public void RunSQL(string sql)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The code will *usually* run for about a minute or two before the exception.  The exception message is two-fold:  ORA-00604: error occured at recursive SQL level 1; and ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `OracleDataReader` and `OracleConnection` implement `IDisposable`, yet you are not disposing of them anywhere.  Dispose != close.

Comment: consider using odp.net with connection pooling.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm#i1006393) for more

Comment: Paul, it looks like calling .Dispose() on the reader and connection solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to call .Dispose() on OracleDataReader and OracleConnection as suggested by Paul Abbott.  Also increased the number of cursors per session from 50 to 150 on the database.